# mapping & loops - counting up or counting down

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am building a time tracking application and my requirement says that any hours past 40 total should be counted as overtime and not regular hours.

Which function is more clear? What can be done to clarify the function? Even the second one at ~ 10 lines seems wordy

## Option #1

```
function calculateOvertime(days) {
    var totalHours = 0;
    var over40 = false;
    return $.map(days, function(hours) {
        var ot = 0;
        totalHours += hours;
        if (totalHours > 40 && !over40) {
            ot = totalHours - 40;
            hours = hours - ot;
            over40 = true;
        } else if (over40) {
            ot = hours;
            hours = 0; 
        }
        return { reg: hours, ot: ot};
    })    
}
calculateOvertime([16,16,16,16]);
```

## Option #2

```
function calculateOvertime(days) {
    var hoursUntilOT = 40;
    return $.map(days, function(hours) {
        var ot = 0;
        hoursUntilOT -= hours;
        if (hoursUntilOT < 0) {
            ot = hoursUntilOT * -1;
            hours = hours - ot;
            hoursUntilOT = 0;
        }
        return { reg: hours, ot: ot};
    })    
}
calculateOvertime([16,16,16,16]);
```

Comment: Does it need to be on a day-by-day basis? If overtime is defined here as > 40 hrs on a weekly basis, why not just sum the week's hours, and get "40 regular, 24 overtime" total. This code assumes the first two days are just "regular workdays", the 3rd is an 8 hour day plus overtime, and the 4th is all-overtime. In reality there'd be overtime _each_ day, wouldn't there? Alternatively, define overtime as > 8 hrs _per day_. It just seems random to do per-day calculation when the overtime is defined per-week.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, it needs to be on a day-by-day basis as its displayed for each day of the week

Comment: ...so again, why not define overtime as anything over 8 hours in a day? Again, if your workday is 9am to 5pm, but you work from 9am to 9pm, you've worked 8 regular hours, and 4 overtime. Yet your code could say that you've worked 12 regular hours with no overtime (wrong), or that everything is overtime (also wrong).

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish your task using only core Javascript, with no reference to JQuery code, in about that many lines. JQuery is overkill for this task.

I applied the following changes to make your code more readable:

1. Reduced knowledge required to understand it (removed JQuery).
2. Reduced the complex portions (see `iCurrentOvertime`).
3. Added Hungarian notation; i.e. prepending integers with "i", arrays with "a", etc.
4. Encased added values together within parentheses (e.g. `iCurrentHours+iTotalHours` becomes `(iCurrentHours+iTotalHours)`).

The new code is below:

```
function calculateOvertime(days) {
  var aHours = [];
  var iTotalHours = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<days.length;i++){
    var iCurrentHours = days[i];
    var iNewHours = (iCurrentHours+iTotalHours);
    var iCurrentOvertime = Math.max(0,(iNewHours - Math.max(iTotalHours,40)));
    iTotalHours = iNewHours;
    aHours.push({
      reg: (iCurrentHours - iCurrentOvertime),
      ot: iCurrentOvertime
    });
  }
  return aHours;
}
calculateOvertime([16,16,16,16]);
```